# ActivityNotFoundException onBackPressed and onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android

Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {Myclass}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

in these two overridden method:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    if(result != null){
        outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
        result.closeDrawer();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**Logcat error:**

> Fatal Exception: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to
>   find explicit activity class {Myclass}; have you declared this
>   activity in your AndroidManifest.xml? at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1801)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1514)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3951) at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3912) at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
>   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4235) at
>   android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4203) at
>   isd.com.al.posapp.DrawerActivity.restart(DrawerActivity.java:737) at
>   isd.com.al.posapp.DrawerActivity$7.onClick(DrawerActivity.java:728) at
>   com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:163)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

Comment: Post your full logcat error.

Comment: In your read your logcat error it was clear :  "have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?"

Comment: Add your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 2):

Declare your activity in AndroidManifest.xml file of your project like as follows

```
<activity
android:name=".YOURACTIVITYNAMEHERE">
</activity>
```